# Formatting amounts with different format parameters with

Tags: c#, string

I would like to format different amounts with various decimal numbers with the `String.Format()` in C#.
I can do this:

```
var amount = 100m;
var culture = CurrencyProvider.Instance.GetCultureInfo("USD");
return String.Format(culture, "{0:C2}", amount);
```

But I would like to parameterize the `String.Format()` methods second parameters' number.
Something like this:

```
var decimals = 2;
var amount = 100m;
var culture = CurrencyProvider.Instance.GetCultureInfo("USD");
return String.Format(culture, $"{0:C{decimals}}", amount);
```

I know it is not right but I cannot describe this differently because I don't know a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you just [escape your interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#special-characters)? `$"{{0:C{decimals}}}"`

Comment: What D M said. In effect, you have to run string.Format *twice*: Once to create the *actual* format string, and once to create your formatted data.

Comment: `amt.ToString($"C{decimals}", culture)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
var decimals = 2;
var amount = 100m;
var culture = CurrencyProvider.Instance.GetCultureInfo("USD");
return String.Format(culture, $"{{0:C{decimals}}}", amount);
```

See string interpolation documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#special-characters).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to get rid of `Format` and put `ToString` instead:

```
return amount.ToString($"C{decimals}", culture);
```

Comment: OP is pretty specific about wanting to use the `String.Format()` function.